# Find the coefficient of $x^{n+1}$ in $x^k(1-4x)^{-2k}$

Tags: combinatorics

I have a question regarding finding coefficients in power series.
The problem is how to find the coefficient of $x^{n+1}$ in $x^k(1-4x)^{-2k}.$

This is how far I got:

$
[x^{n+1}]x^k(1-4x)^{-2k} = [x^{n-k+1}](1-4x)^{-2k} = [x^{n-k+1}]((1-4x)^2)^{-k}
$

I'm looking for a smart substition, because I know that
$[x^n](1-x)^{-k} = {n+k-1 \choose n}.$

However, I have no idea how to and don't know if this is even the way to solve it.
Hints and/or solutions are very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the value of $k$. We have $\displaystyle x^k(1-4x)^{-2k} = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\binom{j+2k-1}{2k-1}x^{j+k}$ so we need $j+k=n+1\iff j=n+1-k$.

Example: If $k=3$ the coefficient is $\displaystyle\binom{n+3}{5}=\frac{n(n^2-1)(n^2+5n+6}{120}\displaystyle$